# How to make a mini cover flow like menu tab (as in the CNBC app) in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitabbar, menubar

Does anyone know how the CNBC apps (under the "Markets" tab) did the mini cover flow like tab menu bar at the top to select the different indexes?  It looks pretty cool...

Thanks,
Charles.

Answer (score 0):

There's a cover flow component ([Open Flow](https://github.com/thefaj/OpenFlow)) That might work for you.

Not sure if it'll render small enough, but it's open source so change to your needs.

Comment: Yes, I had a look at open flow, but it works in a full screen. Also, it is not exactly the look as in the CNBC app. I just thought there might be something out there, or in the iOS SDK. I guess time to hit the books again :-) Thanks for answering!!!